# How to cd automatically after git clone?

Tags: shell, zsh

I want to automatically `cd` to the directory created by the `clone` command after I `git clone`d something.

**Important:** I don't want to alter the syntax for the command (e.g. use an alias/function) because it would break the zsh-completions I get automatically from the `Pretzo` project.

**EDIT**: The reason I didn't pick any answer as correct, is because no answer was given that did comply with the condition above.

I use ZSH, but an answer in any other shell is acceptable as well.

Comment: I like the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/how-to-cd-automatically-after-git-clone/97958#97958 but it need to mention to write that function on `~/.bashrc` file (for example) and for me at least it didn't work, I needed to fix it with the replacing the line :
`/usr/bin/git "$@" 2>&1 | tee $tmp`

Comment: I wonder if cloning repositories is something that you do so frequently that issuing a separate `cd` command after `git clone` becomes a real burden?

Answer (score 53):

Create a function:

```
gclonecd() {
  git clone "$1" && cd "$(basename "$1" .git)"
}
```

(Works for links both with and without ".git")

Comment: I would like to keep using `git clone` because of all the tools that I would have to change if I were not using `git`. [Hub](http://hub.github.com) is aliased as git, oh-my-zsh provides auto-completion, etc...

Comment: @Wildeyes `git` can't change the working directory of your shell, so either way you'll have to wrap it in an alias/function that does what you want and follows it up with the builtin `cd`. If you want to call `hub` instead of `git`, do so in the function. If you want it to only affect the `clone` command, check for the action in the function. etc.

Comment: I noticed that `basename git@github.com:pckujawa/pattern-rec.git` results in pattern-rec.git - do you just leave off the .git extension when you clone?

Comment: @Pat `basename` also takes a suffix argument, so you can do: `git clone $1 && cd $(basename $1 .git)`

Comment: How to write this as a git alias?

Comment: @BenKeil Way late so not likely useful for you, but you would theoretically write it as `git config --global alias.clonecd '!git_clonecd() { git clone "$1" && cd "$(basename "$1" .git)" ; }; git_clonecd'`. Unfortunately at least from my testing it doesn't seem aliases can actually affect the parent environment like that, so the `cd` will have no effect. TL;DR doesn't look like you can, stick to using a function like the original answerer suggests.

Answer (score 24):

`git clone` takes an additional argument: the directory to use. You can make it clone into the current working directory with `git clone URL .`  Then, there is no need to change working directory; you are already there.

If you really want the `git` command to actually change working directory, you can change it to a function which calls the real `git` when necessary:

```
git()
{
   local tmp=$(mktemp)
   local repo_name

   if [ "$1" = clone ] ; then
     /usr/bin/git "$@" | tee $tmp
     repo_name=$(awk -F\' '/Cloning into/ {print $2}' $tmp)
     rm $tmp
     printf "changing to directory %s\n" "$repo_name"
     cd "$repo_name"
   else
     /usr/bin/git "$@"
   fi
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. After I realized there are no internal hooks or something like that, I wrote an almost exact function :)

Comment: If I may, why write the output of git to a file and then read it and then extract the name... if you could simply `name="$(basename $3)`, remove the extension and `cd` to that?

Comment: Because the ultimate indication of where `git` has cloned the stuff is that output. What assurance do we have that the `basename` trick is correct? Here is one way it can break: you run the command `git clone proto://server/path/to/foo.git`.  Now git clones into `foo` not `foo.git`.  Here is another way it can break: you run `git clone /path/to/foo bar`. It clones into `bar` not `foo`.

Comment: For the last one, I just add a check to see if there is a $4, if so swithc to it. I don't understand the `proto` example, wouldn't `foo.git` result in a repository called `foo`?

Comment: Yes, and `basename ../foo.git` is not `foo`. Suppose that tomorrow git acquires some new form of URL where the name is embedded in some other way, or some new way of redirecting to a different directory based on something in the upstream repo.

Comment: Any way to do this without writing to the disc?

Comment: @Wildeyes Yes: have a `/tmp` volume which is in RAM, like any modern Linux does via tmpfs.  Anyway, why would you care about writing to the disk, when you've just done a git clone, which creates directories and writes perhaps hundreds of files to the disk ...

Comment: You're probably right about the whole "nvm if it writes to disk" thing, I was just looking to save extra operations. Thanks a lot Kaz.

Comment: Be careful. it is `git [flags] command [arguments]`, so blindly asking for `clone` in certain position will fail.

Comment: Would adding the "real" path help? Like:
    git_real_home=```which git```
    git()
    {
        ...
        $git_real_home "$@" | tee $tmp

Answer (score 15):

If you provide the local name of the repo, it's really easy using [$_](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars):

```
git clone git@github.com:npm/npm.git npm-local-dir && cd $_
```

But if you don't want to re-type long names, it's a little ugly but doable with sed:

```
git clone git@github.com:pckujawa/pattern-rec.git && 
cd `echo $_ | sed -n -e 's/^.*\/\([^.]*\)\(.git\)*/\1/p'`
```

EDIT: Well, I was going to thank Manav (comment below) for the terse

```
git clone foo/bar && cd !$:t
```

but it **doesn't work in zsh** (something about [how zsh does expansions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) causes it not to treat the first command as input to `!$`). I had to look up what `!$:t` did ([Advancing in the Bash Shell | ${me:-whatever}](http://samrowe.com/wordpress/advancing-in-the-bash-shell/)). `!$` grabs the last part of the previous command and `:t` will "Remove all leading file name components, leaving the tail." Good information, but I wish I could get it to work with zsh (I tried `noglob` with no success).

EDIT: Instead of using `sed` or `!$:t` (which doesn't work in zsh, for me anyway), I found two other options (one adapting https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5685/frederik-deweerdt 's answer with https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/129926/henrik-n 's comment):

```
git clone git@github.com:npm/npm.git && cd $(basename $_ .git)
```

or

```
git clone git@github.com:npm/npm.git && cd ${${_%%.git*}##*/}
```

Comment: `git clone foo/bar && cd !$:t`

Comment: If your repo url ends in `.git` you can use `!$:t:r` to get the folder name.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution for any POSIX shell is to specify the directory to clone to explicitly (any filesystem path) and reuse it:

```
git clone <repository> <directory> &&
cd "$_"
```

and

```
cd -
```

when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an adaptation of the above answer for `OSX`

- `mktemp` requires additional parameter
- `git clone` writes to `STDERR` by default (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685568/458177))

Function:

```
function git {
   local tmp=$(mktemp -t git)
   local repo_name

   if [ "$1" = clone ] ; then
     command git "$@" --progress 2>&1 | tee $tmp
     repo_name=$(awk -F\' '/Cloning into/ {print $2}' $tmp)
     rm $tmp
     printf "changing to directory %s\n" "$repo_name"
     cd "$repo_name"
   else
     command git "$@"
   fi
}
```

Comment: There are 7 answers that display "above" yours. But it may change over time. Such references make no sense on SE, please edit your answer and include a link to the answer you were referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
clone_check() {
  (($? != 0)) && return
  local cmd=$history[$((HISTCMD-1))]
  cmd=("${(@Q)${(z)cmd}}")
  if [[ $cmd = "git clone "* ]]; then
    local dir
    if (($#cmd == 3)); then
      dir=${cmd[3]:t}
      dir=${dir%.git}
      dir=${dir#*:}
    elif (($#cmd > 3)); then
      dir=$cmd[-1]
    else
      return
    fi
    print -r CDing into $dir > /dev/tty
    cd -- $dir
  fi
}
precmd_functions+=(clone_check)
```

It is quite simplistic. It's a `precmd` hook (executed before each prompt), that checks whether the last command line looked like `git clone .../something` or `git clone .../something dir`, guess the directory from that and cd into it.

It doesn't work if you entered `git clone foo; whatever` or `whatever; git clone foo` or `git clone --option repo`...

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the code; I'm using it since a few days. I've just noticed one issue; if you close the terminal right after cloning some project, the next time you open a terminal, zsh complains with two error messages: `CDing into <project>` and `clone_check:cd:17: no such file or directory: <project>`.
The error disappears as soon as the last command you ran before closing the terminal is different from `$ git clone`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental problem with your request that makes it almost impossible to achieve: git is a child process of the shell in this case, and child processes are unable to modify parent's environment in most operating systems. So, the only way of doing this would be from the shell's side - by implementing an alias or function.

You can find additional details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375003/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-of-the-parent-process

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it, but you *could* use this one-liner:

`echo 'project' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git clone https://github.com/username/%.git && cd %'`

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your shell:

```
git(){
  case "$1" in clone) git-clone "${@:2}";; *) command git "$@";; esac
}
git-clone(){ 
   local tgt 
   tgt=$(command git clone "$@" 2> >(tee /dev/stderr |head -n1 | cut -d \' -f2)) ||
      return $?
   cd "$tgt"
}
```

This works by surreptisiously gleaning the cloning target from git's standard error and `cd`'ing into the target if (and only if) the cloning was a success.

It accepts all arguments and options that the regular `git clone` does.

Either you can use the git wrapper and not have to worry about your completions, or you can get rid of the git wrapper and rewire your `git clone` completions to `git-clone`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this based on @frederik-deweerdt answer.

So you can user just clone to `clone` the repo link that are in clipboard, if you inform the repo, it clones than enters.

It is required to install `xclip`.

```
clone() {
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
      local repo=$(xclip -o)
else
      local repo=$1
fi
  git clone "$repo" && cd "$(basename "$repo" .git)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation, also handles additional arguments to the `git clone` command.

Correctly `cd`'s into the folder provided or the default git repo name.

**Usage**

```
gclonecd https://github.com/example/repo
gclonecd https://github.com/example/repo my-custom-folder
```

**Bash Function**

```bsh
# Clones git repo and cd's into it
gclonecd() {
  git_dir="$(basename "$1" .git)"
  git_dir_resolved=${2:-$git_dir}
  git clone "$@" && cd "$git_dir_resolved";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone with same name, same directory and cd you can use:

```
 git clone [clone_url] . && cd $_
```

Comment: Please explain what does `$_` represent.

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers so far seem overly complicated. This works for SSH URIs and any other way of cloning because it simply uses the fact that the thing you just cloned is going to probably be the last modified item in your directory.

```
 gclone () {
    git clone $1
    local ldir=`ls -t | head -1`
    echo $ldir
    cd $ldir
    pwd
 }
```

Comment: Why use `ls` when you know that the name of the repository's directory is the name of the repository by default? You get that name from `basename "$1" .git`. Also, note that you need to quote all your variable expansions and probably handle the case where the `git clone` fails.

Comment: All fair points :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use zsh [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to expand to the [most](https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-expansion-guide-example/#:%7E:text=%23%20Expand%20the%20first%20element%20of%20the%20array) [recently](https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-expansion-guide-example/#:%7E:text=m%20%2D%20Sort%20by%20last%20modification) created [directory](https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-expansion-guide-example/#:%7E:text=/%20%2D%20Expand%20to%20directories) within the current folder.

```bash
git clone git@github.com:example/repo.git && cd *(/om[1])
```

Glob qualifiers are in brackets and can be combined. Here is a breakdown of the qualifiers.

```
# *(/) directory
# (om) sort by last modified (descendingly)
```

It is possible that another directory is created right after git creates the working tree, so I wouldn't rely on it in critical scripts. It should be fine for day-to-day terminal usage.

`[1]` takes the first from the array (yes, it is not `0` in zsh).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the aliases so I solved it like this:

Add this to your zsh `nano ~/.zshrc` or bash `nano ~/.bashrc`:

```bash
## git extra features 
# - clone + cd 
function git() {
    if [ "$1" = "clone" ]
    then 
        command git "$@" && cd "$(basename "$_" .git)"
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh), you can use [the `take` alias](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Cheatsheet) for this.

```bash
take https://github.com/npm/cli.git
```

will clone that repo and then change to its directory.